# Flowdocument Run keep with next

Tags: .net, wpf, flowdocument, paragraph

In a Flowdocument how can I keep with next
When the text wraps I do not want a line break between these two runs

```
Run runMinus = new Run();
runMinus.Text = " -";
runMinus.Background = brushMinus;
pargraph.Inlines.Add(runMinus);
Run run = new Run();
run.Text = "sample";
run.Background = brushParen;
pargraph.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Comment: should mention that this only occurs when Text is wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with zero width nbsp (non-breaking space)

```
run.Text = " –\uFEFF";
```